# Space elevator orbit below GSO but slow enough to be caught by an airplane

Tags: space-elevator, space-tether

I've read a space elevator at GSO 35,800 km (actually above GSO to create the needed counterweight) is not feasible due to lack of current available strength of materials.  Also that a tether at low Earth orbit 200 km is not feasible due to extremely high speeds in the atmosphere leading to very high drag and impossible speeds at which to 'catch' the tether for delivery of payloads/people.

Is there an orbit in between these two extremes that would allow a tether to be short enough to be feasible from a strength and from an atmospheric speed/drag standpoint and what is that orbit?

Comment: GSO isn't enough for a space elevator itself: there needs to be a counterbalance _above_ GSO for the concept to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, while the idea sounds good, it turns out it can't work at all even if we did have the materials for the tether and a plane. The reason is that a space elevator doesn't just have one counterweight! It has two. The first one is the obvious one, out beyond GSO. The second one is the earth! In order for our space elevator to be effective with a plane, the plane is going to have to weigh a very large amount if we want to send reasonable amounts of mass to the top. But that is the boring answer, with lots of ifs and buts. Anything is possible if you drop enough constraints. But say we did have a big enough plane, and could build your space elevator.

Lets do the math to find out what altitude this orbit could be at!

Assume the airplane travels over the surface at 240 m/s along the equator. Also at the equator, the earth rotates at $2\pi r_{earth}/24\mathrm{hr}=460\mathrm{m/s}$. So now our airplane is travelling around the earth at 700m/s in an earth-centered-inertial frame. Our airplane pretty close to the surface of the earth, lets say 10km altitude. This gives a radius from the center of 6,381km.

Now for the orbit. First, we calculate the angular velocity:
$$\omega=\frac{v}{2\pi r_{plane}}=1.097\cdot10^{-4}\mathrm{rad/sec}$$
And finally we use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit) for geostationary orbit:
$$r_{GSO}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{GM}{\omega^2}}-r_{earth}=25744\mathrm{km}$$

Sadly, this is only 30% less than the original value, and still vastly out to space compared to the ISS.

To bring the orbit down to say, 3629km (still much further than the ISS!), the plane would have to travel at
$$\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r^3}}\cdot r_{plane}-v_{earth}=3570\mathrm{m/s}$$

Ouch. And like Baldrickk said, the counterweight has to be much further out than station at the top of the space elevator.

Comment: I've never heard of the bottom counter weight, usually just that you need a counter weight at the top of the orbit and it tapers down as you approach the surface.  And that you need to add more strength as you add 'any' weight to the elevator in the form of payload, and for the actual motion up the elevator as well.  Awesome, I'm actually surprised it cut that much off the top!  I thought I might gain 10% not 30%, but I'm sure a 25,744 km elevator is still beyond our current abilities.  (I was hoping for 15 km from the ground, but 5 from 25k is negligible really!)

Comment: Indeed, we don't think about the bottom counterweight really. It is only there for when there is no elevator weighing the system down. But the reality is that there needs to be tension no matter what with this system, and the tension will be modest to large at the bottom and astronomically high at the orbiting counterweight, hence the technical difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done if you back up and change some of your ideas about what you're building.  Forget the space elevator per se, Quietghost demolished that.  Space elevators must have a net upwards pull or they fall down and that upward pull is only generated by mass beyond synchronous orbit.

However, there is also the concept called the [rotovator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_exchange_tether#Rotovator).  Take a cable and put it in orbit.  It is spun such that the top of the cable is moving forward and the bottom is moving backwards *relative to it's orbit*.  If you build it big enough you can make the bottom part move backwards as fast as the center of mass is going forward--thus to an observer on Earth it would appear to slow as it dipped down, come to a momentary rest and then climb back up and speed up.

Now, if you have god-like ability to make things precise it could come down and pick up a payload that's sitting on surface.  Since getting it ever so slightly wrong would be catastrophic, though, in practice you are going to intercept the cable somewhere in flight.

Note that this system is not tethered to produce a net outward force.  This means there's no free lunch in lifting payloads into space, for every Newton you use to speed up your payload you must also exert a Newton slowing something down.  You also must manage the rotational speed of the rotovator.

A lifter that must bring down as much as it brings up at first glance might seem to not have much value but that's not the case--what comes down need not be what goes up.  Put a mining base on the moon, pack up your refinery slag and use that as the mass to be brought back down.

Comment: Refueling rocket engines of the rotovator that would keep it spinning and flying would be vastly cheaper, as fuel can be delivered by the same means as payload - by airplane.

Comment: @SF Not if you're using chemical rockets, the exhaust velocity is nowhere near high enough.

Comment: I'm happy that you mention catching payload from higher orbits can restore a rotovator's momentum. But instead of sending slag for your up momentum, I would send hydrogen/oxygen bipropellent (If there are indeed rich ice deposits in the cold traps).

Comment: @HopDavid Why?!?!  You get more energy out of mass by discarding it at the low point of the rotovator than by using it as rocket fuel at the center.  Use the hydrogen/oxygen to go somewhere you can't get with the rotovator.

Comment: "Use the hydrogen/oxygen to go somewhere you can't get with the rotovator." Sending down lunar bipropellent would do both. Catching it would provide the LEO rotovator up momentum. After it's caught it could be stored in a LEO propellent depot. Payloads dropped from the tether could have some reaction mass to further slow their re-entry.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Depending on the elevator length; pumping the fuel to the central hub would make angular momentum go up but linear velocity go down. The hub would likely be at some MEO altitude, and I don't think a nuclear reactor would be an overkill for keeping this running, so ISp of ~800 would be quite sufficient to restore the linear velocity. Also, atmospheric drag would stabilize the rotary velocity very efficiently; it's linear (orbital) velocity drop that could be a serious problem.

Comment: @SF If you have a reactor you're talking NERVA type engines, you don't need hydrogen/oxygen.  And this is a case where maximum efficiency isn't that important anyway.  There are no expensive boosters lifting the stuff from the moon, weight isn't a big deal.  A simple system matters more.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: hydrogen is optimal for NERVA, although being a rather ungrateful cargo it could be replaced by something heavier but cheaper and easier in handling. Say, 20-80% oxygen-nitrogen mix that the dipping arm could scoop? Another option is (nuclear-powered) ion engines; they can run on propellants cheaper than xenon.

Comment: @SF Nitrogen would have to be brought up from Earth.  **If** ion engines could produce the needed thrust they would be a good answer as it wouldn't require flinging anything down from the Moon.  (Note: fling, not carry by rocket.  The upper end of a good rotovator cable is moving fast enough to catch a payload coming in from the moon.  Thus you need nothing but course correction engines on an incoming cargo.)  However, that would be quite a bit of engine for the expected use of a rotovator.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: yes, the problem with propellant brought from Earth is that lifting it to CoM of the rotovator would accelerate the fuel to the orbital speed of the CoM and as result slow the rotovator; to recuperate the lost speed the propellant would need to be ejected at speed higher than the loss it caused, meaning ISp above what chemical engines normally provide. But atmospheric nitrogen scooped by the dipping end would be a decent propellant providing we could give it ~600s of ISp.

Comment: @SF. An ISp of 600 gives an exhaust velocity of 5,880 m/s.  That's only half what it cost you to bring it up, not counting gravity losses.  Your rocket needs to eject mass at substantially above orbital velocity if you're going to fuel it from Earth.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: What's orbital velocity at MEO? Notice how the propellant never needs to accelerate much beyond that on the way up, as the arm swinging back moves at velocity much lower than LEO orbital relative to Earth. At no point  you need to accelerate it to 8km/s. There are no gravity losses as understood on launch (everything happens in orbit!) but there is shifting of CoM downwards as you scoop propellant then pull it up towards the hub. But for that you just need to eject it faster (downwards) than you sucked it in which isn't all *that* much.

Comment: @SF The mass is being boosted by the difference in the low arm speed vs orbital speed.  The rotor is going to be in as low an orbit as is practical because it's presence denies any other satellite the ability to orbit below it's upper arm unless it's in an orbit that is resonant with the rotovator.  I don't know how short it could be, I was figuring low orbit speeds.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Well, that's all a matter of design considerations. Completely regardless, I think by the time we have materials and technology to have structurally sound rotovator in orbit, we'll long have engines of decent thrust and >1000s of ISp.

Comment: @SF. I believe we have the materials for a rotovator now.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: But no technology to lift them on anything remotely resembling a realistic budget. Rotovator *could* be made of kevlar, but the mass would make it prohibitively costly to deploy.

Comment: @SF. Orion could do it in one launch.

Comment: Never mind.  Some searching with Google says we can only do a tip velocity of 4 km/sec at present.  No reaching into the atmosphere or anything like it yet.